# Pass multiple items form URL to external basket with add-ons in Woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I've written a plugin with the help of ChatGPT to pass product data with add-ons from a URL an external basket. The issue now comes when I want to add multiple products with add-ons.

The current URL structure that works with one product is as follows:

`https://example.local:8890/example/basket/?add-to-cart=1099&quantity=1&size=16%20(2-3yrs)&shirt_name=MESSI&shirt_number=10&add_matching_socks=true&add_league_patches_to_arms=true`

Below is my plugin code that handles the URL and adds the product to the basket:

```
<?php
        /**
         * Plugin Name: Custom Add to Cart
         * Description: Adds support for adding multiple products with quantities to the cart via URL.
         * Version: 1.0
         * Author: Chris / ChatGPT
         * Author URI: https://example.com/
         * Text Domain: custom-add-to-cart
         * Domain Path: /languages
         */

        function webroom_modify_cart_data($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id, $quantity) {
            // Process add-ons
            $addons = array();
            if (isset($_REQUEST['size'])) {
                $addons['size'] = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['size']);
            }
            if (isset($_REQUEST['shirt_name'])) {
                $addons['shirt_name'] = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['shirt_name']);
            }
            if (isset($_REQUEST['shirt_number'])) {
                $addons['shirt_number'] = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['shirt_number']);
            }
            if (isset($_REQUEST['add_matching_socks'])) {
                $addons['add_matching_socks'] = filter_var($_REQUEST['add_matching_socks'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
            }
            if (isset($_REQUEST['add_league_patches_to_arms'])) {
                $addons['add_league_patches_to_arms'] = filter_var($_REQUEST['add_league_patches_to_arms'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
            }


            // Add add-ons as cart item data
            foreach ($addons as $addon_name => $addon_value) {
                $cart_item_data["webroom_{$addon_name}"] = $addon_value;
            }

            return $cart_item_data;
        }

        add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'webroom_modify_cart_data', 10, 4);

        function webroom_get_cart_item_from_session($cart_item, $values) {
            // Add add-ons from session data to cart item
            if (is_array($values)) {
                foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
                    if (strpos($key, 'webroom_') === 0) {
                        $cart_item[$key] = $value;
                    }
                }
            }

            return $cart_item;
        }

        add_filter('woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'webroom_get_cart_item_from_session', 20, 2);



        function webroom_add_cart_item_data($item_data, $cart_item) {
            // Add custom data to cart item display
            foreach ($cart_item as $key => $value) {
                if (strpos($key, 'webroom_') === 0) {
                    if ($key === 'webroom_add_matching_socks') {
                        $value = $value ? '(+£3.49)' : '';
                    } elseif ($key === 'webroom_add_league_patches_to_arms') {
                        $value = $value ? '(+£1.99)' : '';
                    }
                    $item_data[] = array(
                        'name'  => str_replace('_', ' ', substr($key, 8)),
                        'value' => $value
                    );
                }
            }

            return $item_data;
        }

        add_filter('woocommerce_get_item_data', 'webroom_add_cart_item_data', 10, 2);

        function webroom_calculate_cart_totals($cart) {
            if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
                return;
            }

            foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
                // Check if the cart item was added via URL or manually
                $added_via_url = isset($cart_item['webroom_size']) && isset($cart_item['webroom_shirt_name']);

                // Get the product price based on how it was added to the cart
                if ($added_via_url) {
                    $product = wc_get_product($cart_item['product_id']);
                    $product_price = $product->get_price();
                } else {
                    $product = $cart_item['data'];
                    $product_price = $cart_item['line_subtotal'] / $cart_item['quantity'];
                }

                // Calculate add-ons cost
                $add_ons_cost = 0;
                if (isset($cart_item['webroom_add_matching_socks']) && $cart_item['webroom_add_matching_socks']) {
                    $add_ons_cost += 3.49;
                }
                if (isset($cart_item['webroom_add_league_patches_to_arms']) && $cart_item['webroom_add_league_patches_to_arms']) {
                    $add_ons_cost += 1.99;
                }

                // Calculate item subtotal and total based on add-ons
                $item_subtotal = $product_price + $add_ons_cost;
                $item_total = $item_subtotal * $cart_item['quantity'];

                // Update cart item data with new totals
                $cart_item['data']->set_price($item_subtotal);
                $cart_item['line_subtotal'] = $item_subtotal;
                $cart_item['line_total'] = $item_total;

                // Save updated data back to the cart
                $cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_key] = $cart_item;
            }
        }

        add_action('woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'webroom_calculate_cart_totals');
```

The add-on details that are being passed are as follows:

`size:16 (2-3yrs) shirt name:MESSI shirt number:10 add matching socks:(+£3.49) add league patches to arms:(+£1.99)`

**QUESTION**

Lets say I want to add another item to the URL but with a different shirt name and number e.g KANE and 9. **How should I structure the URL and then update the plugin code to handle the URL and add the items to the basket with add-ons?**

Comment: If you use a GET/POST parameter of the same name twice, PHP will overwrite it, unless you use square brackets in the name - then you will get an array, which you can then easily loop over. So make that `quantity[]=1&size[]=...`, and then you can repeat all that for multiple products.

Comment: But then you will have to loop several different arrays "in parallel." So instead, you could also name your parameters in a different way - `data[0][quantity]`, `data[0][size]`, and then for the next record, you increase the index to 1, etc. That will get you the data grouped a little more "logically."